# StartIndex or Offset attribute for jira xml export

Tags: xml, api, export, jira

I try to export jira issues in XML.

This page https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2064?jql=issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Resolved%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Fixed contains the `issuetype`, `status` and `resolution`  attributes.

If I click on export XML I'll be directed to https://issues.apache.org/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=issuetype+%3D+Bug+AND+status+%3D+Resolved+AND+resolution+%3D+FixedtempMax=100 where my attributes have been saved and `FixedtempMax=100` has been added. `FixedtempMax=100` controls how many item you'll get and if you try to increase `FixedtempMax`, you'll get a 403.

My questions is how to specify a startIndex or an offset in order to get items from 101 to 200 and so on ?

I already tried `startIndex=100` and `offset=100` based on jql specification with no luck.

**Edit:**

If you're logged in, `FixedtempMax` can be set to 200. Still don't solve the problem thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave it here for anyone looking for the same thing.

The attribute to use is `&pager/start=id` and here's a little bash script to download them by slice of 200...

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..58600..200}
  do
      curl --max-time 9000 "https://issues.apache.org/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=issuetype+%3D+Bug+AND+status+%3D+Resolved+AND+resolution+%3D+Fixed+ORDER+BY+createdDate+ASC&tempMax=200&pager/start=$i";
 done
```